# How to import random word from txt file for Wardle game in Python?

Tags: python

I tried to do like this:

```
guess = str()
word = random.choice(open("...\words.txt").read().split())
```

but I keep getting SyntaxError:(Unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
with an arrow on the "read" part.
how can I fix it? the list in the file in different lines.

Comment: In the call to `open` you should specify the correct encoding of the file.

Answer (score -1):

use (r'filepath'), as `\` is an escape character

`r` indicated `raw_string`, it will convert `\` to `\\` in this case

Comment: \w is not an escape sequence. Therefore, using the raw string prefix is irrelevant. Try: *print('\w')* and see what happens

Comment: @ArthurKing I know it's not but somehow it working...

Comment: @AviAd If your code is now working then it's because your path contains a directory name that begins with either n, r, t, b or f

Comment: @ArthurKing non of those BUT the user name not in English so this is maybe the problem